# margin: auto; doesn't center div vertically

Tags: html, css, margin, center

I want to center the text of my anchors (both horizontally and vertically) within their `li` container.

I've read that I can trivially center them orizzontally by using `text-align: center;` on the container.
But to center them vertically I would need to display `li` as a table and `a` as a table cell.

I didn't like this method so I put the text of the anchor into a `div` and tried to center the `div` with `margin: auto;`. For some reason this works only horizontally, even though the `div` is a block element with a defined height. Anyone knows the reason why?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #783F27;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    border: solid medium;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    width: 7em;
    height: 3em;
    color: goldenrod;
}
a div {
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Learning</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><div>Menu</div></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><div>News</div></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><div>About</div></a>
        <li><a href=""><div>Contact</div></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't work. I removed the `div` and applied `text-align: center;` to `li` and `vertical-align: middle;` to `a`. I don't know why but `vertical-align` moves the text just a little bit dow, a very very little bit.

Comment: See the flexbox method.. its very simple

Comment: Yes it is simple with flexbox, but isn't also inefficent? Should I create a flexbox container evry time I want to center a word of text?

Comment: Why not? And how is it inefficient, any sources you can cite? Basically just 3 lines of text, which you are going to write anyway

Comment: What is your problem with flexbox? A flexbox is a very simple and effective way to align content vertically. But in your case i would use `padding` to center my links (see answer below). That is more responsive!

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I found this one https://css-tricks.com/does-flexbox-have-a-performance-problem/. But anyway even with a tie in performances, it would be better to use old rules that work in any case instead of using new tools that may require fallback. (Assuming that the old rules are reasonably easy to implement and that they give the same output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flexbox again - like you did with the `ul`!

Display `.nav ul li a` as a flexbox, then use `align-items: center;`, to vertically center your link.

Your fixed code:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #783F27;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    border: solid medium;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    width: 7em;
    height: 3em;
    color: goldenrod;
}
a div {
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Learning</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><div>Menu</div></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><div>News</div></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><div>About</div></a>
        <li><a href=""><div>Contact</div></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes I knew that, but I din't want to make a flex container just to align a word of text. And anyway I would like to know why the `margin: auto` doesn't work. But thank you anyway for the answer!

Comment: Why not use a `flexbox` to center your text? You can't vertically center relative objects with `margin: auto`, that works only with absolute/fixed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to remove the absolute `height` and `width` of the links and use `padding` instead.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #783F27;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    border: solid medium;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    color: goldenrod;
    padding: .75em 2em;
}
a div {
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Learning</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><div>Menu</div></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><div>News</div></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><div>About</div></a>
        <li><a href=""><div>Contact</div></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```